# Is this a mistake in DWDS?

Tags: meaning

Is the definition of "[verborgen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verborgen)" in DWDS completely wrong, or am I missing something?

Duden has:

1. den Blicken anderer entziehen; verstecken and
2. der Kenntnis, dem Wissen anderer vorenthalten, entziehen; verheimlichen

Comment: Please re-check your Duden: The Verb matching the examples is "verbergen". Verborgen can be a) the participle of verbergen or b) mean to lend as in DWDS.

Comment: You have answers already. The entry for the verb "verbergen" is indeed perfectly fine. It is disappointing for an electronic dictionary that a search does not also point you to the entry for "verbergen".  Wiktionary does that, but the length of the page can perhaps be overwhelming. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verborgen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Verborgen" can be an adjective or a verb, with different meanings. While DWDS has one entry for both, Duden has separate entries. (To be more exact, the DWDS entry seems to be for the verb primarily, but the adjective variant is referred to in the "Bedeutungsverwandte Ausdrücke".)

[As an adjective](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verborgen_abgelegen_unsichtbar_versteckt), "verborgen" is related to the verb "verbergen". The meaning is something like "hidden", "concealed", "covered".

[As a verb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verborgen_verleihen_geben), "etwas verborgen" is kind of the reverse direction of the verb "sich etwas borgen". Let's say you need a tool that you don't own, but that your neighbor owns:

> Ich borge mir die Bohrmaschine von meinem Nachbarn.

> Mein Nachbar verborgt hin und wieder seine Bohrmaschine.

A pair of verbs that works very similarly is "sich etwas leihen" and "verleihen". You could rephrase the example above as

> Ich leihe mir die Bohrmaschine von meinem Nachbarn.

> Mein Nachbar verleiht hin und wieder seine Bohrmaschine.

The difference between "verborgen" und "verleihen" would probably warrant a question of its own. I have read the explanation that it's a regional difference. Others say that "verleihen" is for money, while "verborgen" is for free. I've even found one opinion that the difference is in how careful you are with the borrowed thing.

So no, the entry in DWDS isn't wrong at all, it's just more extensive.

Comment: Interesting that Duden considers *verborgen* an adjective, not even mentioning it's actually a participle.

Answer (score 3):

*Verborgen* can be two things that accidentally have the very same writing:

1. The infinitive of a verb *[verborgen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verborgen)* meaning to lend something
2. The past participle of a verb *[verbergen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verbergen)* meaning "hidden"

So, DWDS is completely correct, you just hit the wrong entry. What is indeed wrong (or, at least, misleading) is the thesaurus which can obviously not differentiate the two verbs.